# How to store database into struct using swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a function to get the database and return it in MutableArray, now I need the database to be in a struct.

Do I need to get the MutableArray into struct or should I get the data straight into the struct?

I have no idea how to approach this or how to store the database into struct

My code:

```
class CrimesInfo: NSObject {

var name: String = String()
var detail: String = String()
var time: String = String()
}
```

The function:

```
func getAllCrimesData() -> NSMutableArray {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    let resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CrimeTable", withArgumentsIn: nil)
    let marrCrimesInfo : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    if (resultSet != nil) {
        while resultSet.next() {
            let crimesInfo : CrimesInfo = CrimesInfo()
            crimesInfo.name = resultSet.string(forColumn: "Name")
            crimesInfo.detail = resultSet.string(forColumn: "Detail")
            crimesInfo.time = resultSet.string(forColumn: "Time")
            marrCrimesInfo.add(crimesInfo)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on here. Here are some of my thoughts:

1. Your `getAllCrimesData` actually gets `crimesInfo`. "Data" or "Into, pick one, stay consistent.
2. Your `getAllCrimesData` return an array of all kinds of data mushed together. There's no need for this, fill out some structs immediately, rather than worrying about parsing the array into structs later.
3. There's almost never a reason to use `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or their mutable versions in Swift. Use native Swift type.
4. Use safe `guard let` or `if let` checking to deal with the optionality of the `resultSet`, rather than using an implicitly-unwrapped optional.
5. There's no reason to make `CrimesInfo` a Class
6. There's no reason to make `CrimesInfo` inherit from `NSObject`
7. There's no reason to pre-fil the `name`/`detail`/`time` with an empty String. I doubt you want a crime named `""`.

Here's how I would write this:

```
struct CrimeInfo: NSObject {
    let name: String
    let details: String
    let time: String

    init(name: String, detail: String, time: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.details = details
        self.time = time
    }

    init(fromResultSet: FMResultSet) {
        self.init(
            name: resultSet.string(forColumn: "Name"),
            details: resultSet.string(forColumn: "Detail"),
            time: resultSet.string(forColumn: "Time")
        )
    }
}

let CrimesIntoQuery = "SELECT * FROM CrimeTable"

func getAllCrimesInfo() -> [CrimeInfo] {
    let database = sharedInstance.database!
    database.open()

    guard let resultSet = database.executeQuery(CrimesIntoQuery, withArgumentsIn: nil) {
        else return []
    }

    var crimes = [CrimeInfo]()

    while resultSet.next() {
        crimes.add(CrimeInfo(fromResultSet: resultSet))
    }

    return crimes
}
```